# POST parameter not working in twilio REST api

Tags: php, angularjs, twilio, twilio-api

I am trying to (and have to) use the [twilio rest api](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/ip-messaging/rest) to create/update channel for ip messaging using angularjs.

Below is my code: The problem i am facing is, the `POST` parameter is not working. Channel is created with name is null value. Please help me.

```
.controller('updatechannel',function($scope, $http) {   
   $http({
     method : "POST",
     url : "https://ip-messaging.twilio.com/v1/Services/IS*******/Channels" ,
     headers:{
       'authorization': '*******',
       'Content-Type':
       'application/x-www-urlencoded'
     },     
     data :{
       "friendlyName":"NEW_FRIENDLY_NAME"
     }  
   }).success(function(data,status, header, config) {     
     $scope.channelname = data;
   }).error ( function (data, status, header, config) {
     $scope.channelname =  'ERROR';   
   }); 
})
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! Could you please edit your code so it's starting only with 4 spaces indentation here? Basically remove all the `>` - it will make the question more readable for everyone!

Comment: Can I ask why you need to use the REST API for this? It's not safe to keep your credentials in the client side as a malicious attacker could steal them and abuse your Twilio account. Also, you should be able to use the IP Messaging JS library to create and update channels safely.

Comment: I tested many ideas. I have a php code to create and update channels. But parameters are not working too. That's create channel with name NULL value in every code also php with curl .

Answer (score 1):

try something like this.

```
var con = "your url"
var params = $.param({                            //your parameters
            friendlyName: "NEW_FRIENDLY_NAME",
            ormore:"one more parame"
        });


$http.post(con, params, config
               ).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {

                   $scope.channelname = data;
               })
               .error(function (data, status, header, config) {

                   $scope.channelname =  'ERROR';

               });
```

Comment: Thanks for answer, but parameter values are not work. Channel is created with friendlyName = NULL ,not "NEW_FRIENDLY_NAME".

Comment: try..

var params = {
       friendlyName: "NEW_FRIENDLY_NAME"
}